# How to have multiple view templates based on clientid in angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive

I am working on a project where I need to load view components based on client Id.
Basically trying to present the same data model with drastic HTML differences.
Example:

- Login HTML for one client may be different from another
- I may need to send more/fewer request params respectively using the same API.
- This is just a login component example.
- It can be any other view like header, footer, HomePage, etc.

> Currently I am using ****ngComponentOutlet*** approach.I am deciding what component to load for which client when app loads first time based on clientId and set some global data model and it will load the respective component accordingly.

*login.component.html* -Base component where I want to render login template(which is nothig but another angular component) for respective client
`<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="data.loginTemplate"></ng-container>`

[image]
Can someone help here? Is this the right approach? Can anyone suggest a better way to achieve the same?

**Note:** Don't want to use ****ngIf*** directive for some reason.

Comment: Hi Bharat, thanks for the question. Unfortunately, half of it is rendered as code. Could you edit the question so that it is more readable? Just remove the backticks around the text, I guess.

Comment: wouldn't you just create several different view components and a service that feeds them data.

Comment: @digital-pollution Could you please elaborate a bit if possible?

Comment: create normal angular components with the different layouts that display the view, create a service that pulls through the data from the api, import that service into each component. It's in the official "heroes" angular tutorial. Sorry I'm not meaning to be rude but here on stack overflow you should make an attempt and we'll help you out from there.

Comment: @digital-pollution Never mind. Thanks for the input. I already have a service to pull/feed data to the components (different layouts). But then in the main view, I have to have ****ngIf*** in order to decide what layout to render, just trying to avoid it if possible. Today I have 10 different templates but it may grow in the future. That's the reason I went with ****ngComponentOutlet*** but not sure this is the best way to do this or maybe I am overthinking this.

Comment: I get you're trying to show the same data in different templates just route to the components separately in the routing module then determine which component to route to in the app.component.ts you don't need to join them together in a master template. do the heroes tutorial it will make sense https://angular.io/tutorial